# Wordpress menu gets unlinked from theme randomly.

Tags: wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress site.
The main nav menu keeps completely disappearing and this seems to be happen randomly.

I have to go back into appearance > menus > manage locations > and reassign the menu to its theme location.

It's happened about 3 times now and I need to figure out how to stop it happening.

Has anyone fixed this before? When I google this problem all that comes up is posts abouts single menu items disappearing but not about it unlinking from the theme.

Comment: Have you tried turning off plugins?

Comment: Cant really do that as it a live site and it only happens now and then so the site would be broken while plugins are off. could it be a memory problem? The site has 3 menus that all get unlinked together when it happens.